# Size of libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 building from two different methods

Tags: linux, sqlite, build

I have a question about the size difference of libsqlite3.so.0.8.6 built using two different methods. Hoping to get some insight from the community here.

I downloaded latest sqlit3 sources (version 3.36.0), canonical (sqlite.tgz) and amalgamated (sqlite-autoconf-3360000.tar.gz), from the official website. Then built from both source types for Linux and compared the size of resulting library (libsqlite3.so.0.8.6).

The one built from canonical ('original') source is about 1.1M in size, while the one from amalgamated sources has a size of about 1.5M.

Could someone please help me understand the reason for difference in size for the library which is built from identical source code, but from two different 'methods' (for the lack of a better word)?

While the size difference may not matter if the library is running on a desktop-like machine, it does matter (in my case) since it is meant to run on a embedded device.

What I tried:

I have tried to compare the build logs from the two methods, but could not identify anything significant that could result in a smaller size. If there is something in particular I should be looking out for, please mention.

Thanks,

Aashish

Comment: A random OS, confirm size difference. ( configure, no options ). sqlite3-3.36: 882.4MB stripped . ..... sqlite-autoconf-3360000: 1.2MB stripped. ..... Why : I don't know.

Comment: The canonical zip file build process first creates the sqlite3.c amalgamation and then compiles it, so I'd expect resulting object files to be the same size. Different compiler flags and/or optional SQLite components, maybe?

Comment: My host environment is Ubuntu 16.04. Both builds were done without any additional configure options (all defaults). No changes to include or exclude sqlite components either. I did not strip the built library, though. @Shawn Yes, I noticed that also. The resulting amalgamated source file is identical to the pre-amalgamated source. Maybe I need to dig deeper into the build processes for both methods to find something significant.

Answer (score 1):

I found the difference. I edited the configure.ac of amalgamated source to add and remove some of the compilation flags. Doing this disabled some extensions and reduced the final library size.

Removed:

-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5

-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4

-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_GEOPOLY

-DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1

Added:

-DNDEBUG

I could have seen this sooner if I was looking a bit more closely at the build logs.